# How to create array of ImageButtons ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, imagebutton

I have a problem creating an array of ImageButtons and to show them on screen.

This is what I did:

```
ImageButton[] aImageButton = new ImageButton[9];
Panel1.Visible = true;
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    aImageButton[i] = new ImageButton();
    aImageButton[i].ID = "ImageButton" + (i + 1);
    aImageButton[i].Width = 100;
    aImageButton[i].Height = 100;
    aImageButton[i].BorderWidth = 0;
    aImageButton[i].ImageUrl = "http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/font-awesome/svg/circle-empty.svg";
    aImageButton[i].Visible = true;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(aImageButton[i]);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl());
}
```

Basically I have created a panel where I want to show my `ImageButtons`.
I created an array called `aImageButton` and then using a for loop I want to create the buttons, but they not showing on the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl());
```

replace it for:

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br /><br />"));
```

or delete it.

Comment: Could you explain why adding two line break tags fixes the problem?

Comment: I had a similar problem some weeks ago, I used the line break and it fixed. Can't really give a scientific explanation. Just trying to help.

Comment: Still I can`t see the result on the screen when I run it.
Maybe I miss something? How do I make the ImageButtons apear on the screen?

It`s killing me ...

Comment: @PeterToth check out my edited answer. You might also try to replace the .svg image for a .png, I'm providing the link to make it easier for you:
`http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/font-awesome/png32/512/000000/circle-empty-512-000000.png`

Comment: Like I said earlier.
Still no change

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers won't display svg inside 'image' input type for security reasons. Please check this article.
http://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/